# Display short expiry items with if condition

Tags: php, date, if-statement

I am using SQL date format to display short expiry items in warning label as following.

Is it works outside of query?

```
if("STR_TO_DATE( '$expire', '%Y-%m' ) BETWEEN CURDATE() AND DATE_ADD( CURDATE(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH)")
{
     $display_date = "<label class='label label-warning'> $expire </label>";
}elseif("STR_TO_DATE( '$expire', '%Y-%m' ) <= DATE(now())")
 {
     $display_date = "<label class='label label-danger'> $expire </label>";

}else{
     $display_date = "<label class='label label-success'> $expire </label>";

 }
```

Comment: It's not the way. You have to write conditions in php rather than using mysql directly(which will never going to work). Fetch data from SQL first, then use those using PHP to write conditions.

Comment: @LovepreetSingh - I have fetched `$expire` from database now i am checking the condition of expiry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use code like:

```
$expireDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($expire));
$now = date("Y-m-d");
if ($expireDate > $now && $expireDate < date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+3 month"))) {
    $display_date = "<label class='label label-warning'> $expire </label>";
} else if ($expireDate <= $now) {
    $display_date = "<label class='label label-danger'> $expire </label>";
} else {
    $display_date = "<label class='label label-success'> $expire <label>";
}
```

Comment: `$expire` date format is like 2018-06 then should i use this line `$expireDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($expire));`

Comment: '2018-06` looking like its month not day. Also you only can compare dates using `"Y-m-d"` format.